Providing an IPython Interpreter During Development in a Hatch Project
I have a project using Hatch as a build system for pyproject. My pyproject.toml looks like this:
[project]
name = "demo"
description = "Demo Project"
version = "0.0.1"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.12"
dependencies = []

[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "pytest",
    "ipython",
]

[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[tool]

[tool.hatch.envs.default]
type = "virtual"
path = "venv"

I prefer using IPython as a REPL instead of just regular Python, since it adds a lot of features and nice-to-haves during development.
I've specified the dependency during the test phase in my optional dependencies, but I can't seem to find the egg on-disk or a way to execute it.
Is there a way for me to use IPython in a Hatch project like this without making it a project dependency? It's only relevant during local development.

What you have looks correct.  How are you installing?

Here's a way to achieve this:
Create a separate virtual environment: You can create a virtual environment specifically for development purposes this way, you can install IPython and other development tools without affecting the main project dependencies.
Update your pyproject.toml: You can specify the virtual environment path in your pyproject.toml and ensure it's used during development1
pyproject.toml:
[project]
name = "demo"
description = "Demo Project"
version = "0.0.1"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.12"
dependencies = []

[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "pytest",
    "ipython",
]

[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[tool.hatch.envs.default]
type = "virtual"
path = "venv"
python = "3.12"

Use the following command to activate the virtual environment and install IPython:
hatch env shell
pip install ipython
This way, IPython will be available in your development environment without being listed as a project dependency.
Does this approach work for you?
